# Vba copy row to another workbook based on condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 wb and need to copy value to another wb based on condition: 
If the value in the column F of wb2 appears in column F of wb1, then I need to copy value in the column G of wb2 to column G of wb1. The code is below:

```
   Dim LtRow As Long
   Dim m As Long, n As Long

   With wb2.Worksheets.Item(1)
      LtRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
   End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Item(2)
      n = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   End With

   For m = 1 To LtRow
       With wb2.Worksheets.Item(1)
           If .Cells(m, 6).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Item(2).Cells(m, 6).Value Then
              .Rows(m).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Item(2).Range("G" & n)
               n = n + 1
           End If
       End With
   Next m
```

I don't know why the code didn't work at all! Where is the problem in my code?

Comment: What are you trying to reference with your properties `wb2.Worksheets.Item(1)` and `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Item(2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

To see what your excel files look like wasn't an option for what you are trying to do. Especially because in you have many empty rows. Anyway, this works for me:

```
Sub CopyConditions()

    Dim Wb1 As Workbook
    Dim Wb2 As Workbook
    Dim Wb1Ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Wb2Ws1 As Worksheet

    Set Wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set Wb1Ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Differences")

    'open the wb2
    Dim FullFilePathAndName As Variant
    Dim StrOpenFileTypesDrpBx As String
    Let StrOpenFileTypesDrpBx = "xls (*.xls),*.xls,CSV (*.CSV),*.CSV,Excel (*.xlsx),*.xlsx,OpenOffice (*.ods),*.ods,All Files (*.*),*.*,ExcelMacros (*.xlsm),.xlsm"
    Let FullFilePathAndName = Application.GetOpenFilename(StrOpenFileTypesDrpBx, 1, "Compare this workbook ""(" & Wb1.Name & ")"" to...?", , False) 'All optional Arguments

        If FullFilePathAndName = False Then
            MsgBox "You did't select a file!", vbExclamation, "Canceled"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open(FullFilePathAndName)
            Set Wb2Ws1 = Wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
        End If


    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim sCell As Range

    'loop through each cell in column F until row30 because with the empty cells in the column we can't use Rows.count
    For Each rCell In Wb1Ws2.Range(Wb1Ws2.Cells(1, 6), Wb1Ws2.Cells(30, 6)) 'Wb1Ws2.Cells(Wb1Ws2.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp))

        'if the cell column F is equal to a cell in wb2 sheet1 column L
        For Each sCell In Wb2Ws1.Range(Wb2Ws1.Cells(3, 12), Wb2Ws1.Cells(Wb2Ws1.Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp))

            If sCell = rCell Then
                rCell.Offset(0, 1) = sCell.Offset(0, 1)
            End If

        Next sCell

    Next rCell

End Sub
```

How does it go for you?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Did I understood well what you are trying to achieve? Was it an error while you run the code or the result is not what you are expecting? Do you understand what I tried to do?

Comment: Yes I understand your code, it's really what I want to achieve but I still got the same result (not what I'm expecting)

Comment: Ok. Could you edit your question and add some pictures of your excel showing the initial data and the expected result so we can visualize better?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to post the data here so I posted it in a thread in the excelforum. If you have an account there could you help me plz: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1145990-vba-copy-row-to-another-workbook-based-on-condition.html

Comment: I just tried again and it works. I opened your wb1, insert a new module, paste the code above, run it and in the sheet Differences Ly is just next to 50000 (i had to first delete the decimals of the amounts in that sheet because it was with comas instead of points) What was the result for you?

Comment: In your sheet Differences, did you check the amount ? as i told you for me it was 50000,00 in format General so it could not match with the amount in the other workbook.

Comment: Check your question in excelforum. i attached back your file. If it doesn't work from that, I do not know what i can do to help you.

Comment: Thank you,it finally work! It's just a range problem because I indicated the wrong column

Comment: Hi there, I got the error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set in the line: "For Each sCell In Wb2Ws1.Range(Wb2Ws1.Cells(3, 12), Wb2Ws1.Cells(Wb2Ws1.Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp))" Where is the problem?

Comment: I forgot to declare `sCell`, sorry. Just add `Dim sCell As Range`. I just edited my answer as well. Tell me if it works fine now